# Getting Null values while Passing datas through Intent to another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am getting null Values while passing datas through Intent from 1 activity to another activity.

Passing from 1Activity:

```
                       int s = position;    
          String str=adapter.getId(position);   
                int Type=DeviceType;
                Bundle bunch=new Bundle();
                bunch.putString("id", str);
                bunch.putInt("DeviceType",Type);
                bunch.putInt("position", s);
                Intent It=new Intent();
                It.setClass(PYSActivity.this,GridImages.class);
                It.putExtras(bunch);
                startActivity(It);
```

Retriveing here in 2 Activity:

```
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

               Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
               AppID=b.getString("id");
               DeviceType=b.getInt("DeviceType");
               Position=b.getInt("position");

               list=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter1=new LazyAdapter1(this,mStrings,like,Rate,Id,img); 
    list.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

Activity 1:

```
    int myInt = 5;
    String myString = "hi";

    ...
    Intent Intent = new Intent(...);
    intent.putExtra("string_key", myString);
    intent.putExtra("int_key", myInt);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2:

```
    int getInt;
    String getString;
    ...

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Read the extras data if it's available.
    if (extras != null)
    {
        getInt = extras.getInt("int_key");
        getString = extras.getString("string_key");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are creating bundle just use intent.

```
            it.putExtra("id", str);
            it.putExtra("DeviceType",Type);
            it.putExtra("position", s);
```

Comment: I have used,    int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");  eventhough am getting nullvalue